# How to get downloads' website origin (App Store / Play Store)

Tags: android, ios, itunes, tracking, google-play

I'm having some doubts about if it's possible to achieve this:

- I've got a landing page, a website with two links pointing towards the stores (iTunes Store or Play Store links for the application)
- The user clicks any link and gets to the download official page inside the corresponding store.
- User downloads (or not) the app *****

How can I know which was the user's action in this point?
Is there any tool/code to track this?

EDIT: Maybe I didn't explained myself enough. I know how to link to the stores, but the thing is, how can I know if, when the user is already in the app details page in the Play Store (or iTunes), downloads the application BY having came through my landing page, not just searching around.

I mean, which is the source of the download, where is the user coming from to download it. I wonder if there's any flag, parameter, tool or something to track this.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Play store only have to add this link.

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.name.package

and In the AppStore

> http://itunes.com/apps/developername/appname

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained myself enough. I know how to link to the stores, but the thing is, how can I know if, when the user is already in the app details page inside the Play Store, downloads the application BY having came through my landing page, not just searching around.

I'll add this in the original post to avoid missunderstandings but thanks for taking your time to answer TeRRo!